# Object passed as prop from root component, not rendering changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement React to a game engine. I am just creating a new engine instance and passing as prop to React root. And I can't change Engine.

```
const engine = new Engine(configurator);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App engine={engine}/>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

**App.tsx**

```
export interface ComponentProps {
  engine: Engine;
}

class App extends React.Component<ComponentProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <SaveList saves={this.props.engine.savedGames}
                  newCharacter={this.props.engine.newGame.bind(this.props.engine)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is I can't update my components whenever a property of engine changes. Let's assume a `SaveList` component that shows saved games, I am passing props like this.

```
<SaveList 
   saves={this.props.engine.savedGames} 
   newCharacter={this.props.engine.newGame.bind(this.props.engine)}
/>
```

And **saveList.tsx**

```
export interface SaveListProps {
  saves: Save[];
  newCharacter: () => any;
}

class SaveList extends React.Component<SaveListProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {this.props.saves.map((save, i) => {
          return <li key={i} className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            {save.characterName}
            <span className="badge badge-primary badge-pill">Days: {save.days}</span>
          </li>
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Whenenever I click new game button, I can see that object is actually changing and a new game is pushed into `engine.savedGames`. But I can't make `SaveList` to re-render the change. I can also see the new element pushed into array using React developer tools

[image]

I am not sure how can I handle this two way binding issue. How can I connect this object and watch changes and re-render on change using React?

Comment: post ur `SaveList` code

Comment: @riwu Added source code.

Comment: Add the component where you create new games too.

Comment: @riwu It is a method in Engine which is a package. It is as simple as `this.savedGames.push(new Character());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top level App will never rerender when engine changes because it exists outside of React. You need to either put your engine into `state` at the top level, and change it through calls to `setState` or use the `forceUpdate` api to force React to update when your engine changes.

If you're willing to take on MobX as an extra dependency, this could potentially be as easy as just marking the engine as an observable and all components that consume it as observers. (this worked for the OP)

As a sidenote, it seems like what you’re doing is at odds with React itself. React is meant to control when your app renders, but you’ve used an external engine to dictate when things should render. You might be served better if you were to use a standalone virtual DOM library in close conjunction with your engine. Something like lit-html perhaps.

Comment: I'm curious, having dealt with this before what is the best practice for having external objects in react? I've heard complaints from people not wanting to replicate the entire js object state in react because its already modelled in plain js and it feels unnecessary, but that seems like the best way to do it to me? Any ideas?

Comment: Another question from me, if you can't change any code from Engine. What would you do?

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven forceUpdate is the only way to do it. You might wanna check out MobX and see if that can help you if you don’t wanna wire things up manually.

Comment: @MattPengelly forceUpdate as the primitive, and if you wanna take on another dependency MobX works well for this.

Comment: @m0meni would the js object change be handled somewhere in middleware then? Since the MobX reducers would be changing App state and not the external js state?

Comment: MobX would observe when the external changes. Then it would update whatever components consume that external that are decorated with observer. MobX doesn’t have reducers or middleware really...are you thinking of Redux?

Comment: I connected MobX successfully, thank you @m0meni! Please add MobX to your answer too. So it can be visible to anyone easily.

Comment: Yes i was thinking of redux, i was thinking they were close to the same, clearly i was mistaken. Appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Re-render happens every time there is a setState() call, in this case, the object is being changed outside of what react is aware of, you could have the engine emit an event and then call setState and/or remodel the data in react state and call setState to fix it I believe.

Comment: Thank you, used mobx to convert arrays to observable and connected to React.